# How can I determine whether a transaction completed successfully?

Tags: transactions, validation

How can I determine whether a transaction completed successfully?

Basically I'm going to have a Cron task that will perform an instruction from my Smart Contract. This instruction, once performed, will send me back a txid. Since it's a Cron Task, I want to be 100% sure that the transaction went through. How can I make sure that my transaction is good (after having performed program.instruction().rpc()) and when in case it has failed, restart it, and those until it is good

Comment: Have you tried fetching the transaction using its signature and checking for commitment status and whether there are any errors?

Comment: I've improved objectivity and precision of the main question.  Can you try to distill the remainder to only what's pertinent to what you'd like to check and how you'd like to respond to failures?  All of the "Cron Task" stuff is superfluous, likely to distract from the core and prevent getting to a high quality answer quickly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things you need to check:

1. Did it land on chain?
2. Did it execute successfully?

For 1) call [getSignatureStatuses](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getsignaturestatuses) until you see a `finalized` commitment (guarantees its landed on chain).

For 2) call [getTransaction](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettransaction) with a 'finalized' commitment and check to ensure there wasn't an error.

These are the RPC calls, but there are relevant similar calls on the web3 library.

Generally this is the only *robust* mechanism for knowing a transaction succeeded.

Comment: So if I follow your advice, I do my instruction, then I do an await of getSignatureStatuses to make sure that the tx has landed on the chain (I guess the function waits to have a result ?) If fail, I start again, if success, I check then by recovering the transaction itself, and if in the meta I have no error then it's good, if not I also start again right ?

Comment: Yep, you'd want to loop and poll `getSignatureStatuses` until its done. However, once the chain moves forward 150 slots from your initial submission (technically the blockhash associated with your initial submission), if your transaction hasn't been found it will have never made it into the chain. The real logic to test for this is a bit complex, the simplest workaround is to only loop and check for ~2 minutes, and then timeout.